# Change Channel name with a command and also send embed with it

Tags: embed, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot which it will change the specifc name of the channel

Code

```
if(command === `${prefix}openslot`) {

    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor("#1bc643")
        .setTitle("Sucessfully opened slot for PREMIUM RANK!")
        .addField("Created At", message.author.createdAt)

        .setDescription("SYSTEM");

    message.channel.sendMessage(embed);
    channel.setName('Reserved_Slot')
```

.then(newChannel => console.log(`Channel's new name is ${newChannel.name}`))
  .catch(console.error);

```
    return;
}
```

And also I'm new to discord.js (started a month ago)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Never-mind, I found it myself.

```js
message.guild.channels.find("name", "general").setName("Testing");
```

Thanks for correcting my grammar.