# I want it to change channels name automatically with Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Friends, I made a code and when our game server is active in my code, the bot changes the color of the message it writes to green or something, but I want it to change the name of the room, which is my code.

No matter how hard I try, I can't change the name of the room he sent that message to, can you please help?

```
var TICK_N = 0;
var MESSAGE;
var LAST_COUNT;
var STATUS;

var STREAM_DISPATCHER = undefined;

var loop_callbacks = []; // for testing whether loop is still running

const log = function(level, message) {
    if (level >= LOG_LEVEL) console.log(`${new Date().toLocaleString()} :${level}: ${message}`);
};

const getPlayers = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetchTimeout(URL_PLAYERS, FETCH_OPS, FETCH_TIMEOUT).then((res) => {
            res.json().then((players) => {
                resolve(players);
            }).catch(reject);
        }).catch(reject);
    })
};

const getVars = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetchTimeout(URL_INFO, FETCH_OPS, FETCH_TIMEOUT).then((res) => {
            res.json().then((info) => {
                resolve(info.vars);
            }).catch(reject);
        }).catch(reject);
    });
};

const bot = new Discord.Client(BOT_CONFIG);

const sendOrUpdate = function(embed) {
    if (MESSAGE !== undefined) {
        MESSAGE.edit(embed).then(() => {
            log(LOG_LEVELS.DEBUG, 'Update success');
        }).catch(() => {
            log(LOG_LEVELS.ERROR, 'Update failed');
        })
    } else {
        let channel = bot.channels.get(CHANNEL_ID);
        if (channel !== undefined) {
            channel.fetchMessage(MESSAGE_ID).then((message) => {
                MESSAGE = message;
                message.edit(embed).then(() => {
                    log(LOG_LEVELS.SPAM, 'Update success');
                }).catch(() => {
                    log(LOG_LEVELS.ERROR, 'Update failed');
                });
            }).catch(() => {
                channel.send(embed).then((message) => {
                    MESSAGE = message;
                    log(LOG_LEVELS.INFO, `Sent message (${message.id})`);
                }).catch(console.error);
            })
        } else {
            log(LOG_LEVELS.ERROR, 'gücelleme kanalı secilmemiş');
        }
    }
};

const UpdateEmbed = function() {
    let dot = TICK_N % 2 === 0 ? 'LustRP' : 'Roleplay';
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        //"cdn.discordapp.con/atac..... sunucu logonuz"
        .setAuthor("LustRP", "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/985288535588368434/985665669334990938/Unbenannt-.png")
        .setColor(0x2894C2)
        .setFooter(TICK_N % 2 === 0 ? '⚪ LustRP' : '⚫ LustRP')
        .setTimestamp(new Date())
    if (STATUS !== undefined) {
        embed.addField(':warning: Sunucu durumu:', `${STATUS}\n\u200b\n`);
        embed.setColor(0xff5d00)
    }
    return embed;
};

const offline = function() {
    log(LOG_LEVELS.SPAM, Array.from(arguments));
    if (LAST_COUNT !== null) log(LOG_LEVELS.INFO, `Server offline ${URL_SERVER} (${URL_PLAYERS} ${URL_INFO})`);
    let embed = UpdateEmbed()
        .setColor(0xff0000)
        .setFooter(' LustRP')
        .setDescription('\n\u200b\n **Sunucumuz şuanlık kapalıdır. En yakın zamanda aktif verilecektir.** \n\u200b\n')
        .setImage("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/974298125407772702/987879840319414272/kafi1.png")
        .addField('Sunucu durumu', ':x: Kapalı', true)
        .addField('Sıra kuyruğu', '?', true)
        .addField('Aktif oyuncular', '?\n\u200b\n', true);
    sendOrUpdate(embed);
    LAST_COUNT = null;
};

const updateMessage = function() {
    getVars().then((vars) => {
        getPlayers().then((players) => {
            if (players.length !== LAST_COUNT) log(LOG_LEVELS.INFO, `${players.length} players`);
            let queue = vars['Queue'];
            let embed = UpdateEmbed()
                .setColor(0x00ff00)
                .setDescription('\n\u200b\n **Sunucumuza aktif verilmiştir. İyi roller dileriz.** \n\u200b\n')
                .setFooter(' LustRP')
                .setImage("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/974298125407772702/987879840558514186/AKIF1.png")
                .addField('Sunucu durumu', ':white_check_mark: Online', true)
                .addField('Sıra kuyruğu', queue === 'Enabled' || queue === undefined ? '0' : queue.split(':')[1].trim(), true)
                .addField('Aktif oyuncular', `${players.length}/${MAX_PLAYERS}\n\u200b\n`, true);
            // .addField('\u200b','\u200b\n\u200b\n',true);
            if (players.length > 0) {
                // method D
                const fieldCount = 3;
                const fields = new Array(fieldCount);
                fields.fill('');
                // for (var i=0;i<players.length;i++) {
                //   fields[i%4 >= 2 ? 1 : 0] += `${players[i].name}${i % 2 === 0 ? '\u200e' : '\n\u200f'}`;
                // }
                fields[0] = `**Oyuncular:**\n`;
                for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
                    fields[(i + 1) % fieldCount] += `${players[i].name.substr(0,32)}\n`; // first 12 characters of players name
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                    let field = fields[i];
                    if (field.length > 0) embed.addField('\u200b', field, true);
                }

                // method A
                // let maxLen = 8;
                // var text = '';
                // for (var i=0;i<players.length;i++) {
                //   var eol = false;
                //   if ((i+1) % 3 === 0) eol = true;
                //   text += paddedFullWidth(players[i].name,eol ? players[i].name.length : maxLen);
                //   if (eol) text += '\n';
                // }
                // embed.addField('Spelers',`**${text}**`,false);

                // method B
                // embed.addField('Spelers','\u200b',false);
                // for (var player of players) {
                //   embed.addField('\u200b',player.name,true);
                // }
                // for (var i=0;i<3-(players.length%3);i++) {
                //   embed.addField('\u200b','\u200b',false);
                // }

                // method C
                // let playerNames = Array.from(players.values()).map((c) => `**${c.name}**`).join(', ');
                // embed.addField('Spelers',playerNames,false);
            }
            sendOrUpdate(embed);
            LAST_COUNT = players.length;
        }).catch(offline);
    }).catch(offline);
    TICK_N++;
    if (TICK_N >= TICK_MAX) {
        TICK_N = 0;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < loop_callbacks.length; i++) {
        let callback = loop_callbacks.pop(0);
        callback();
    }
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Channel name with a command and also send embed with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47383103/change-channel-name-with-a-command-and-also-send-embed-with-it)

Answer (score 0):

Since you already defined a `channel` you want to send embed in - you simply can do: `channel.setName("CHANNEL_NAME")`

Comment: can you show me where to put it